# ProgressBar not showing in some devices

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar

I have the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.pontai"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.markupartist.android.widget.ActionBar
        android:id="@+id/actionbar"
        style="@style/ActionBar"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dip"
        app:textStyleActionBar="@style/TextViewStyleHeader"
        app:title="@string/app_name" />

    <com.fb.design.SegmentedButton
        android:id="@+id/main_action_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:btnText1="@string/sb_friends"
        app:btnText2="@string/sb_search"
        app:btnText3="@string/sb_summary"
        app:gradientColorOffEnd="@color/segmented_button_off_end"
        app:gradientColorOffStart="@color/segmented_button_off_start"
        app:gradientColorOnEnd="@color/segmented_button_on_end"
        app:gradientColorOnStart="@color/segmented_button_on_start"
        app:gradientColorSelectedEnd="@color/segmented_button_selected_end"
        app:gradientColorSelectedStart="@color/segmented_button_selected_start"
        app:whichButtonIsSelected="0" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dip"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_line" >
    </View>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonAddFriends"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_input_add"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:height="40dp"
                android:width="40dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/search_box"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="@string/type_here_to_filter"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:padding="10dp" >
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
            style="@style/GenericProgressBackground"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <ProgressBar style="@style/GenericProgressIndicator" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/android:empty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="@string/empty_results" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My Activity has a AsyncTask that upon completion does the following:

```
((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

So, basically I have a LinearLayout holding my ProgressBar and, when I have the data I need, I set the visibility to GONE for this linearlayout.

This is working find on my Galaxy Nexus, but it's not working on my API 8 Emulator and also in the Galaxy S2, using a custom ROM.

Has anyone ever seen this?

My worst case scenario will be removing this linearlayout with a progress bar from the XML and add a ProgressDialog in the code.

Regards,
Felipe

**UPDATE**

This is how I defined the styles.xml

```
 <style name="GenericProgressBackground" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:background">#77ffffff</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>

    <style name="GenericProgressIndicator" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:indeterminate">true</item>
    </style>
```

**UPDATE2**
I fixed the issue

```
 <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I added the style coming from the android attributes and that alone worked... I have no idea why it didnt work with the style I created... it's weird.

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Good to ear that you find a solution

Comment: You could thanks me by voting me up ;-)

Answer (score 6):

On some devices the progress bar could not appear because in Settings -> Developer Options -> Transition Animation Scale is OFF.

Switching this setting to ON (usually x 1) will make the progress bar to appear again.

I guess there is a proper explanation about that, but I do not have complete answer why animations off make the progress bar to not work.

Comment: It's not working well,can you please let me some other tips @Sniper

Comment: Hey @ManikandanK what kind of issue do you have? Does the progressbar work on some device but doesn't work on other? Doesn't your progressbar work at all (on every single device)? Can you see the progressbar on the screen? If you see the progressbar does is spin?

Comment: For me it was Animation Duration Scale I had set to off.  It is popular to disable these settings to make transitions between apps faster and make the phone appear to run faster.

Comment: for me it was also animator duration scale. After tunring it on (to 1x), I could see the progressbar again

Answer (score 4):

What is the result of using

```
<ProgressBar
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.ProgressBar.Large"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Comment: Should this be inside the LinearLayout?
If not, how can I hide the progressbar?

Comment: Yes you can put this into your LinearLayout `<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
            style="@style/GenericProgressBackground"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >` But don't forget to add android:layout_width="match_parent" on your LInearLayout

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately this doesnt work.
Actually, what you have suggested is already defined in my styles.xml

Comment: Sure, find it in the UPDATE2 section

Comment: It already works, Alexandre.
I posted the solution above. Thanks :)

Comment: This worked for me. In my case, I used style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge" and progress bar was visible on older devices but not on the newer ones. Changing the style to style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.ProgressBar.Large" Made it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen on some devices when animations are turned off. Turn your animations on again and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I wanted to add a progress bar on my splash screen in xml layout file, I was able to see the progress bar showing on Eclipse preview of the screens, but when I run the code, it was invisible and it made me crazy for a couple of hours. Finally I solved the issue by adding the progress bar in a FrameLayout, with the splash background image drawing in a different RelativeLayout which is a lower layer child of the FrameLayout. My background image was a 9patch image, so maybe it was overwriting my progressbar on runtime. But here is my solution:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/splash" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I found a better solution. If you do not mark the "fill area" on 9patch, you cannot add any content, or the content you added becomes invisible. To deal with it, mark the "fill area" of your 9patch image wisely, and set your FrameLayout's background to this 9patch image. Then you can see the children of the FrameLayout in the area you marked. For further information about 9patch images, see [link](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch)

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this was switching to Linear layout from Relative Layout. Worked Quite Well. Code below hope it helps

activity_main.xml:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/leniar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">


        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBarlite"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"


            android:gravity="center"
            android:theme="@style/ProgressBarlit" />

        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-1dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

            </WebView>
        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Yes I have a WebView and SwipeRefreshLayot Too But i Guess you can just copy this code and delete those segments. and if wondering how i make the progress bar show in the center of the screen:

MainActivity.java:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


     this.progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBarlite);
     mySwipeRefreshLayout = 
       (SwipeRefreshLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
     this.webview = findViewById(R.id.webview);


WebViewClientImpl webViewClient = new WebViewClientImpl(this);
                webview.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);


                webview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mySwipeRefreshLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);


 public class WebViewClientImpl extends WebViewClient {

            private Activity activity = null;


            public WebViewClientImpl(Activity activity) {
                this.activity = activity;

            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView View, String url) {

//here i set the domains the webview can browse
                if (url.contains("ur domain"))
                    return false;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                activity.startActivity(intent);

                return true;


            }

//here i show the progress bar
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                mySwipeRefreshLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                webview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

//here i hide the progress bar
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mySwipeRefreshLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                if (mySwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }

            }

//here i hide the progress bar and also load a locally saved error messege
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String url) {
                view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mySwipeRefreshLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                if (mySwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }

            }

            public class MediaWebView extends WebView {

                public MediaWebView(Context context) {
                    super(context);
                }

                public MediaWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                    super(context, attrs);
                }

                public MediaWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
                    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onWindowVisibilityChanged(int visibility) {
                    if (visibility != View.GONE) super.onWindowVisibilityChanged(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }

        }
}
```

For this to work it's really important that you call out the gravity to be "center" for both the progress bar and the linear layout containing it

```
<LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"/>


        <ProgressBar
            android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

here is my styles.xml:

```
<resources>
 <style name="ProgressBarlit" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/progressback</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">32dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxWidth">50dp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="ProgressBardrk" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccentDarkprgress</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">32dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxWidth">50dp</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">32dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">100dp</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

Hope It Helps and i know it answers more than just this question but you will find your answer in here

Answer (score 0):

I had a weird issue on an HTC U11 where our battery saver was automatically turned on, I turned it off but still, the spinner was not showing up.

Then I turned off developer settings totally, relaunched the app and then the Spinner start showing up, hope it helps someone.